# How do you view TestFlight crash logs?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, crash-reports

I have submitted my app to TestFlight and i have deliberately made the app on my device crash, but i don't see where i can see these crash logs.

BTW i want to see other people's crash logs on the app, not the one in the settings menu.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 20):

There are 2 places where you can see your crash logs (well, users testing your app):

## Method 1: via appstoreconnect.apple.com

1. Login to appstoreconnect.apple.com
2. Select "My Apps"
3. Chose your app from there
4. Select the "Test Flight" tab
5. You should see the list of your app versions along with build etc
6. Note down / remember the current (or live) one.
7. On the same screen (left menu) notice you now have "Crashes" under "Feedback"
8. Select "Crashes", this will display all crashes to all of your testers
9. Notice the info isn't the full log, but something you can download with the last column being the user's feedback on what/how it crashed

Usually a user would get a message saying "Sorry, app-xxx crashed" and ask him to comment, that's your last column here, also they can submit a screenshot which can be select on the left menu in the same way.

## Method 2: from XCODE

1. From XCODE:
2. Select Window -> Organiser (well; OrganiZer if you're a Yankee)
3. This will give you a new screen with all your apps
4. Select the APP you need, and then select the "Crashes" tab from the top
5. Select the version from the left menu, and this should give you more on these crashes
6. Please note that: Unless the users agrees to "send Apple and it's 3rd Party (i.e. yourself) crash reports..." then you would not see anything here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You have Analytics enabled on the device and set "sharing with developer" to true to see the crash report in TestFlight.

Answer (score 19):

In Xcode 6.3 crash logs have moved into Organizer window.

It might take some time and a restart of the crashed apps for the logs to show.

Comment: Restarting Xcode helped for me. Some recent builds (and therefore crashes) weren't showing up until the restart.

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on [@dogsgod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29728748/1032372) and responding to @KevinLeStarge's comment.

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to: Window -> Organizer
3. Click the "Crashes" Tab

Here's an example:

[image: Crash log example]

Answer (score 10):

Well, I'm not sure if this will help, but it helped for me:

Go to iTunesConnect -> My Apps and choose your app. Then in Versions section scroll to Version Release and check one of radio buttons (**Automatically release this version** or **Manually release this version**)

If you have luck, all crash logs (old ones too) will apear in new Organizer's Crash window after few minutes (Xcode 6.3). Be sure to close Organizer's window and open it again after making changes in iTunesConnect.

Comment: @KevinLeStarge I added an answer below