# My app crashes on specific iPhone on others it works fine

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I almost finished developing my app, already have multiple testers on TestFlight, Today strange thing happened my app is crashing (it is not getting data from server when on main screen) on my iPhone only, It works fine even with the same account on other devices but it crashes on my specific iPhone, my friend had the same problem from the day 1 but I thought it was because of his device, but now I'm having the same problem.

1. Tried installing on other phone via test flight and using same user, everything works.
2. Tried building from Xcode on my iPhone - Still get error when trying to get entries from backend.
3. Tried deleting and installing the same version that works on other phones via TestFlight and still get the same error

Can't seem to catch the error.

edit: Cocoa pods needed update sudo gem update cocoa pods
edit2: Updated iPhone to the latest version, problem resurfaced

About the app: Authentication is done via AWS cognito.
as our backend uses Graphql, I was wondering maybe it's something related.

Possible cause of the problem:
What I've noticed is that, even if I delete the app and clear Safari cache, when I download the app again and launch it, it logs in with the last logged in account.

edit3: ok very strange but it started getting data and showing on main screen (so it works) it happened same time yesterday, starting to think that it's related to time somehow (we convert server time to actual location based time for user)

Comment: Go onto Xcode and pull the crashes in from TestFlight [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728516/how-do-you-view-testflight-crash-logs). Then update this post with that information as well as the iOS version and the device model.

Comment: One thing you should remember is that in most cases it is not about the device but about the iOS version. If you updated Xcode it probably also uses newer SDK so this also can be a reason. Anyway always remember to tell us on which system you are testing the app and which SDK you are using to build it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What is the phone type and the OS type. Do you have a firebase crashylitics installed or something to give you specifically what is happening?

My knee-jerk on these are some layout issue, or some object that is declared on a storyboard or xib file that is fubar only on an iPhone 8Plus or something. Like some error that only occurs on larger devices because of some silly reason.

If you are able to repro on an x-code run you should really print out your server response and check for any irregularities.

And finally, why does not getting something from the server cause a crash? What if the user does not have the internet? You should really 'handle not getting the data from the server on the main screen' more elegantly.

Comment: 1. Iphone Xr latest OS, No Firebase, Tried on most iphones from iPhone 6 to iPhone Pro, works fine on other devices. I'm thinking that there is some problem with cache on my iPhone

Comment: If its that try changing the package name of the app.

Answer (score -1):

Just figured it out, it was because of the outdated cocoa pods,
I thought when I updated Xcode to latest version they would update automatically but I was wrong.

`sudo gem install cocoapods`
solved the problem

edit 2: didn't help, after updating to latest iOS still same problem