# Test Flight keeps crashing, but app is okay in development env (React Native)

Tags: xcode, react-native, testflight

I am uploading my **React Native** app to TestFlight and I am seeing that it crashes whenever I try to open it at a specific screen and I am not able to replicate that crash in the development debug environment. I have connected my phone to my computer so I can view the logs located in my device and I make the app crash on purpose so that I can see what the specific issue is. Here is the main warning that I keep receiving.

```
failed to get process exit details for UIKitApplication:(my bundle id) : Could not find specified service (113)
```

I am not sure as to what this specifically means and I was wondering why I can not replicate this specific crash in the development environment ? and is there a way in which I can solve this specific issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a release schema to bundle the app and upload it on TestFlight?

Comment: @SaachiTech Yes I have set it to a release schema

Comment: You may want to try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58387719/3784556 to get more logs or use a service like https://www.bugsnag.com/ to find the actual bug.