# Loading Screen Issue with .NET MAUI iOS Deployment on TestFlight

Tags: .net, mobile, blazor, maui

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently facing an issue with deploying my .NET MAUI application on iOS using TestFlight. The application is built with a combination of .NET MAUI and Blazor, and it works perfectly fine when running it on the simulator or a local device in both debug and release modes. However, when deploying it through TestFlight, I encounter a persistent "loading..." screen, and the application fails to proceed further.

I have followed the guidance provided in the video tutorial [link to the tutorial: "Sharing code between app and web"], and I have completed my initial draft. Now, I'm struggling to troubleshoot this loading screen issue and determine what might be causing it.

Here are some additional details about my setup:

Environment: .NET MAUI with Blazor
Deployment Method: TestFlight for iOS
Issue: Stuck on "loading..." screen upon deployment
I'm seeking advice on how to effectively troubleshoot this issue. What steps can I take to identify the root cause? Are there any specific logs or debugging techniques I should utilize to gain more insights into what might be going wrong during the TestFlight deployment process?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: There is an similar issue: [iOS app crashes using TestFlight](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11276). You can try the workaround in it. And you can check if there any log report in the appdeveloper connect -> testflight.

Comment: I can't find my solution here. I've tried to SdksOnly and None. 

Could it be bc my project strucutre is a .net maui that has a dependency project reference to a class library that holds all my blazor components and http request to my backend?

Comment: You can refer to this case: [How do you view TestFlight crash logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728516/how-do-you-view-testflight-crash-logs)?. And did you add `<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>` in the csproj?